# Unable to add new tag using XML::Twig module in perl

Tags: xml, perl

i am trying to check whether the tag is present/not and adding the same if its not available. In this case i am trying to add new tag :`<testProd>true</testProd>` inside `<characteristics>`  tag.

My xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<test testProp="false">
<Env>
  <log>XM</log>
  <uvmversion>1.2</uvmversion>
</Env>
<classes>
  <class instances="1" name="total"/>
</classes>
<characteristics>
   <pctest>true</pctest>
</characteristics>
</test>
```

Script:-

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;
my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
 pretty_print => 'indented',
 twig_handlers => {
         testProd => \&Check_tag,
         characteristics => sub {
                              $_->insert_new_elt( last_child => 'supportsMVV' )->set_text('true'); 'true' );
    },
},
);

$twig->parsefile('applying.xml');
$twig->print;    

sub Check_tag{
 my $item = $_->tag;
 if (defined $item) {
  print "'testProd' tag is already defined in given xml file.\n ";
 exit;
}
}
```

Not sure whats wrong with my script.I am able to print the output of xml using `'$twig->print;'` statement which has required changes that i am expecting. But in my file `applying.xm`l i can't see the changes in it. Anyone please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`twig_handlers` is IMO one of the features of `XML::Twig` that's both amazing, but also unduely confusing.

I'd suggest *not* using it, unless you need to incrementally parse or pre-process your XML.

So I'd tackle your problem more like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my $xml = XML::Twig -> new ->parsefile('applying.xml');


#get_xpath finds all characteristics nodes in the tree, and allows you to 
#iterate. "//" means any depth. 
foreach my $element ( $xml -> get_xpath('//characteristics') ) {
   $element -> insert_new_elt ( 'last_child' => 'supportsMVV') -> set_text('true');
}

$xml -> set_pretty_print('indented'); 
$xml -> print;
```

It's using `get_xpath` to walk the XML tree, and find all the `characteristics` nodes, before altering each of them. I feel this is both cleaner, and less confusing.

You can also use `xpath` to test for conditions in your XML as `XPath` is a fairly comprehensive way of interpreting an XML document. Or just do it 'perlishly' within the iterated element.

Anyway, the reason you're not seeing your thing being changed,  is you're not actually writing out the changes - `$xml -> print;` only changes the file if you're doing `parsefile_inplace`.

But I'd suggest you don't want to do that, either - just save a copy of your output.

E.g.:

```
open ( my $output, ">", "applying.new.xml" ) or die $!;
$xml -> print ( $output );
```

Comment: Sobrique, I don't want to create new xml file. I want to modify in original file. Because i am working on file which is in version control system. Could you please give the example of using 'parsefile_inplace.' ?

Comment: Does your version control not support overwriting the file? E.g. close the filehandle you read, open it for writing, spit out the modified XML.

Comment: yes, It supports. I am using perforce , I will open it for edit and want to make the changes in-place. And also your suggestion is good for not using ''twig_handlers' but right now i don't want to change my code. It works fine as expected except writing it to file is not happening. Could you please update my code with file inplace technique?

Comment: That's literally as simple as replacing `parsefile` with `parsefile_inplace`. Although functionally, it does the same thing as I'm suggesting - reads in the file, then overwrites it with the processed output.

Comment: Sobrique, I t works fine as expected, But one problem is if i do diff against the revision in perforce depot file and local depot. It is showing diffs with other lines where extra spaces got added and header <?xml version='1.0' ?> is replaced with <?xml version="1.0" ?> double quote "1.0" .. why is it so? I am expecting to see only the diff of  tag which i added.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading data from a file, making changes to the in-memory copy of the data and then **not** writing the changed data back to the original file.

At the end of your code, you need to add something like:

```
open my $out_fh, '>', 'new_applying.xml' or die $!;

print $out_fh $twig->print;
```

Comment: Dave,I have added two lines at the end of my code. It's not writing the data. it is displaying on terminal and inside applying.xml i can see some Hash reference :XML::Twig=HASH(0xdf8638)